# Branching and Merging in TFS

Tags: tfs, branching-and-merging, tfvc

In my SSIS project, I created a MAIN folder in TFS and then created 2 branches (Dev1 and Dev2) from the same package which is present in the Main.
I did some changes in the Dev1 and other changes in Dev2. Now when I am trying to merge both the SSIS Packages in the Main, it is giving error (Conflict while merging). I am able to merge only one Dev package with the MAIN package. As soon I try to merge the second Dev package with the Main, it shows conflict error.

```
       -------                  Dev1 
      /       \
 ------------------------       Main
      \               
       -------------            Dev2
```

Answer (score 3):

Conflict resolution is a common activity when doing parallel development in separate branches. It happens because changes were made to the same (set of) files and those changes have hit the same piece of code.

SSIS makes this problem larger due to the fact that it has a tendency to change the order of things in files and sometimes generates new GUIDs for activities that were already in the workflow. When this happens, it causes a lot of changes almost everywhere in the file(s).

To resolve the conflict you have to select each file that is showing conflicts and follow the conflict resolution process through Team Explorer. When you select a conflict to resolve the editor will show up with the two different versions (one showing Dev2 and one showing Main (incl the changes from Dev1)). You will need to manually select which pieces of code to retain and how the files should be merged.

Unfortunately, there is no graphical representation, so you need to be very familiar with the internal file format in order to make no mistakes. After completing the merge you can first test your changes locally. If they were merged successfully, you can check-in the changes, if you've made a mistake just undo all pending changes and perform the merge process again.

The [complete steps to perform merges are documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/resolve-team-foundation-version-control-conflicts). The [BI Developer Extensions](https://bideveloperextensions.github.io/) offer additional features to Visual Studio to make working with version control easier. [Especially SmartDiff can save your hide in cases where SSIS has regenerated the file structure](https://bideveloperextensions.github.io/features/SmartDiff/).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I will try to merge manually with SmartDiff.